# Constantly Losing Internet Connection 2Wire HGV3801

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

It seems like I will continuously lose my internet connection every 5-15 minutes for about 10-20 seconds.  Very annoying.  I have AT&T U-Verse coming through the 2Wire HGV3801.  The wireless portion is disabled.  I have a Linksys E1200/N300 router connected to the 2Wire over ethernet.  I have DMZPlus enabled on the 2Wire, so that it forwards all traffic to the E1200.  I have about 15 devices that could use wireless at any time (desktops, laptops, phones, tablets, consoles).  I am running DD-WRT on the E1200.  The 2Wire is on 192.168.0.1/24.  The E1200 is statically assigned on the WAN side and the LAN is on 192.168.1.1/24.  I have DHCP enabled on both, although I could technically disable it on the 2Wire.  I am using a mix of static and dynamic addresses on the E1200.  I noticed that the outage can occur when a device connects to the network.  It seems to happen often when a specific laptop connects, but that just may be a coincidence.  I am using OpenDNS IP's on the E1200 and blocking port 53 from clients.  Note that I never lose wireless connectivity, but Windows does report loss of internet when the outage occurs.  It kicks off and on so quickly and randomly that I can't actively determine what happens.  It seems to occur more when I have higher network traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Linksys E1200 was on the fritz.  It now completely fails on the WAN port.  I am using a new device and it has operated without a hitch for several days now.